# Receber solicitação de mensagem via Whatsapp com webhook

Tags: node.js

Preciso criar um webhook para responder a uma solicitação vinda do Whatsapp.

Criei a rota webhook no servidor apontando para o meu computador e estou usando o ngrok para testá-la.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consigo fazer uma solicitação usando o insomnia.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho algumas dúvidas sobre como receber os dados do Whatsapp.

Qual verbose devo usar para obter os dados do Whatsapp?

Como posso ler estes dados recebido?

Answer (score 0):

Gostaria de entender o motivo de terem votado negativo a minha dúvida, o mas "engraçado" é que infelizmente ninguém soube responder.. Mas vamos lá, pode ser interessante para algum novato.

E espero que quem precise melhore a minha reputação.

Apontei o webhook para o post que estou usando para criar o menu no controller
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro da controller você trata os dados recebidos de acordo com o a sua solução.
Mandei um console.log para teste

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]